# Parameters.Add(Overloads) vs Parameters.AddWithValue(Potentially losing characters)

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm have little experience with parameters I've read in several threads here that `Parameters.add` is deprecated (which even the compiler says) and that you should use `Parameters.AddWithValue` instead.

But Now I´ve found [this](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) post which gives an explanation for why you should use `Parameters.Add` since it sends the specified DataType to the Server, and when you use `Parameters.AddWithValue` the function has to infer the DataType converting it potentially losing characters when the collection doesn't match.

Well knowing this. Isn't it a good idea to go back to `Parameters.Add` or should I stick with `Parameters.AddWithValue` well aware of the conversion it has to make?

Comment: I'd look for an overload of `Add` that isn't deprecated.

Comment: It's only [`Add(string,object)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameterCollection.cs,73) that is deprecated, so far as I'm aware.

Comment: Is this tagged `mysql` because the question actually concerns `mysql` or is that a mistake? I doubt `SqlParameterCollection` is relevant to MySQL. (The correct tag for SQL Server is `sql-server`.)

Comment: That article should be "Stop using AddWithValue and don't use the Add(string,object) overload either".

Comment: @JeroenMostert Im using it with mysql

Comment: [MySqlParameterCollection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlparametercollectionmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlparametercollection-add-overloads) doesn't have an `AddWithValue` method at all, so I guess @JeroenMostert is correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted article already contains suggestions about how to avoid your problem.

Basically, you need to use the right overload of `.Add`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

As you can see from MSDN, there's only one overload marked `[Obsolete]`. I would use the most appropriate `.Add` overload that fits my needs.

Comment: Ill stick to the overloads of .Add